# get string of text from url scheme works in appdelegate but not in viewcontroller

Tags: ios, json, swift, url, url-scheme

so I have a url scheme namely - `appname//`

and when I go to a website in safari that has a response with`appname//jsonurl` it catches it correctly in the appDelegate but when I try to use it in my app the variables are empty because my application function is being called after the son function

code appDelegate -

```
    //url scheme
var urlScheme: String!;
var pathScheme: String!;
var queryScheme: String!;

var checkbool : Bool = false;


func application(app: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, options: [String : AnyObject]) -> Bool {
    //get contents of url
    urlScheme = url.scheme;
    pathScheme = url.path;
    queryScheme = url.query;
    NSLog("URLLLL");
    //NSLog(urlScheme);
    //NSLog(pathScheme);
    //NSLog(queryScheme);

    return true;
}
```

ViewController code

viewdidload

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: ("loadJSON:"), name: UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification, object: nil);
```

joon function

```
       func loadJSON(notification: NSNotification){
            NSLog("app entered foreground");

            getValidJson();

            //play video using specific player
            if(videoPlayer == 0){
                //call inlineVideo();
                inlineVideo();
                resizeScreen();
            }else{
                //call 360 video player
                makeSphere();
                resizeScreen();
            }

            createImageView(videoPlayer);

            //add seeker
            view.addSubview(timeRemainingLabel);
            view.addSubview(seekSlider)

            //add target listeners for the seeker
            seekSlider.addTarget(self, action: "sliderBeganTracking:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchDown);
            seekSlider.addTarget(self, action: "sliderEndedTracking:", forControlEvents: [UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside, UIControlEvents.TouchUpOutside]);

            self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor();
        }
```

how can I get the values from my `url scheme` and use it in my view controller, currently my application function is being called after the loadJSON function, and it should be the other way around

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change your observer code to

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: ("loadJSON:"), name: "customNotif", object: nil);
```

and call the notification in the AppDelegate `openURL` function

```
func application(app: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, options: [String : AnyObject]) -> Bool {
    //get contents of url
    urlScheme = url.scheme;
    pathScheme = url.path;
    queryScheme = url.query;
    NSLog("URLLLL");
    //NSLog(urlScheme);
    //NSLog(pathScheme);
    //NSLog(queryScheme);

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("customNotif", object: nil)
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In App delegate create object Like this

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

var urlScheme : String = "";
var pathScheme : String = "";
var queryScheme : String = "";

  func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
   return true    
}
```

In view controller Use app delegate Object like this

```
pathScheme = String(appDelegate.pathScheme);
queryScheme = String(appDelegate.queryScheme);
```